# froala unordered list not showing in editor

Tags: plugins, froala

I'm using Froala for my website CMS.
I'm trying to add unordered lists to the editor.
I've added the lists plugin like so:

```
<script src="js/plugins/lists.min.js"></script>
```

and when I init the editor, I add it to the tool bar buttons

```
    toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen','undo', 'redo' , '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 
                     'outdent', 'indent', 'fontSize' , 'lists', 'color',
                     'clearFormatting', 'insertTable', 'insertImage',  
                     'insertFile', 'html'],
```

but it doesn't show up in the editor.
Why?

p.s.: I also tried adding 'insertUnorderedList' instead of 'lists'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using an incorrect setting in the toolbarButtons.
The correct terms are *formatUL* and *formatOL*, not *lists*.

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much!